# Confirm this approach to deal with missing values with Neural Network

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a feature that looks like this (I do not have enough rep to upload an image, I can only describe it, in any case here is the link --> https://ibb.co/g9YQgQX):

- the distribution is gaussian, min is 0, max is 1
- corresponding to value 0, there is a huge bar which corresponds to 3/5 of the data points

If I use rule based algorithm (RF, XGboost) I can get very good results, but I'm struggling with NN (not sure if it depends from this or from other causes).

Can you please confirm this is a distribution that a NN can deal with? Otherwise, what do you advice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: RF and XGBoost; rule based?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what you're doing because the axes are unlabeled BUT yes the NN could deal with this distribution but probably poorly.  However you should look closely at what you are trying to achieve.  When I look at it I think of dividing this in to two separate issues and would train the NN on the non-zero distribution and have something separate to handle the zeros.  Conversely, you could consider this as a very imbalanced data set and there are a number of ways/literature on dealing with those eg. [deep NN's](http://203.170.84.89/~idawis33/DataScienceLab/publication/IJCNN15.wang.final.pdf), [general advice](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) (really just google "neural networks imbalanced datasets")

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mike. Please note that the variable I'm speaking about is a feature, not a target variable, so techniques for imbalanced dataset (which I'm already using) are little use. Thing is I have many features for this kind of distributions. This one in particular represents, given a loan, how much a customer has paid back in the last year. If follows a sort of Gaussian distribution, except there are a lot of customers that pays 0 back...

Comment: Just for clarity: you say you're successfully using RF and XGboost.  Are you using those to model the feature or is it that you have constructed models using RF and XGboost and are trying to use NN's but you think that _this_ feature and others like it are the reason the NN doesn't seem to be working?